# Are the estimates of the intercept and slope in simple linear regression independent?

Tags: regression

Consider a linear model

$y_i= \alpha + \beta x_i + \epsilon_i$

and estimates for the slope and intercept $\hat{\alpha}$ and $\hat{\beta}$ using ordinary least squares. This [reference](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/298) for a mathematical statistics makes the statement that $\hat{\alpha}$ and $\hat{\beta}$ are independent (in their proof of their theorem).

I'm not sure I understand why. Since

$\hat{\alpha}=\bar{y}-\hat{\beta} \bar{x}$

Doesn't this mean $\hat{\alpha}$ and $\hat{\beta}$ are correlated? I'm probably missing something really obvious here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Go to the same site on the following sub-page:

https://web.archive.org/web/20160914012624/https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/278

You will see more clearly that they specify the simple linear regression model *with the regressor centered on its sample mean*. And this explains why they subsequently say that $\hat \alpha$ and $\hat \beta$ are independent.

For the case when the coefficients are estimated with a regressor that is *not* centered, their covariance is

$$\text{Cov}(\hat \alpha,\hat \beta) = -\sigma^2(\bar x/S_{xx}), \;\;S_{xx} =  \sum (x_i^2-\bar x^2) $$

So you see that if we use a regressor centered on $\bar x$, call it $\tilde x$, the above covariance expression will use the sample mean of the centered regressor, $\tilde {\bar x}$, which will be zero, and so it, too, will be zero, and the coefficient estimators will be independent.

[This post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/115011/in-simple-linear-regression-where-does-the-formula-for-the-variance-of-the-resi/115040#115040), contains more on simple linear regression OLS algebra.

Comment: I would consider using $Cov(\hat \alpha, \hat \beta | X)$ instead of $Cov(\hat \alpha, \hat \beta)$. Otherwise it feels that $\bar x$ and $S_{xx}$ need to be replaced by population counterparts. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Why does zero covariance imply independence? Are $\hat\alpha$ and $\hat\beta$ bivariately normally distributed? See http://probability.ca/jeff/teaching/uncornor.html.