# help to understand how residual standard deviation can differ at different points on X

Tags: residuals

I read in more than one place that residual standard deviation can differ at different points on X. I cannot understand this statement. 
I find this while learning the very basics, so for me the standard deviation of the residuals is a single unique number, and I see no way how this single number can change depending on the xi being a simple number calculated across all samples. 
I guess I must be missing some necessary intermediate concept/steps.
I would be very grateful is someone can explain this to me in a very basic way

---

My question was not clear trying to improve it: what is not clear to me is if there is such a thing as the standard-deviation of a specific point/sample, ie. if we have x <- 1:5, y <- c(10,6,12,15,2) and y ~ x, is there a formal concept of standard deviation of residual of a single sample and a formula to calculate it ? ie. can I, and if yes how do I calculate the standard deviation of the residual corresponding to x=1,y=10 ? of that corresponding to x=2,y = 6? ...

Comment: Your question concerns the distinction between *errors* and *residuals*.  It can be informative to examine an extreme case. Consider fitting a line to the data $(0,\epsilon_1), (0,\epsilon_2), (100,\epsilon_3)$, where the $\epsilon_i$ are identically distributed *errors* and thereby have the *same* variances. The fit will pass right through that last point and split the first two points. Thus, the *residuals* $(\epsilon_2-\epsilon_1)/2,  (\epsilon_1-\epsilon_2)/2,$ and $0$ will vary for the first two points but will *never* vary for the last point.

Comment: You speak about residuals, no problem with them being different, that is what I would usually expect.   My doubt is about how different observations, within the same sample, can have different standard deviations, this is what my course literally says.

Comment: Data will be whatever they will be, so it's pointless to opine about what their values are.  But the *distributions* of the residuals must differ even though the distributions of the errors are assumed not to. In the example I gave, the residual at $x=100$ is *invariably* zero while the residuals at $x=0$ clearly vary.  Thus their distributions must differ with different $x$.

Comment: My previous comment was wrong due to having moved my mind to something else and rereading in a hurry forgot that I had actually asked about residual variance, and not variance of observations. Sorry about that. Thanks for you comments/explanations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT :**

My answer was indeed wrong (thank you @Glen_b). I cannot delete it as it has been validated.

All I can do is to redirect you to this answer written by [Alecos Papadopoulos](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/115011/in-simple-linear-regression-where-does-the-formula-for-the-variance-of-the-resi).

In short, if you have a simple model:
$y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1*x_i + u_i$
then your $ith$ residual will be like $\hat{u_i} = y_i - \hat{y_i} = (\beta_0 - \hat{\beta_0}) + (\beta_1 - \hat{\beta_1})*x_i + u_i$.

If $Var(u_i) = \sigma$ then $Var(\hat{u_i}) = \sigma(1-\frac{1}{n} - \frac{(x_i - \bar{x})^2}{\sum(x_i^2-\bar{x}^2)})$.

All the calculation are explained in the link, and I could not do any better.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I see now that my question was not clear, I try again 
If I understand well you use the term deviation like a synonim of residual. What is not clear to me is if there is such a thing as the standard-deviation of a specific point/sample, ie. if we have x <- 1:5, y <- c(10,6,12,15,2) and y ~ x,
is there a formal concept of standard deviation of  residual of a single sample and a formula to calculate it ?  ie. can I, and if yes how do I calculate the standard deviation of the residual corresponding to x=1,y=10 ? of that corresponding to x=2,y = 6? ...

Comment: I think my edition answers your question now.

Comment: There's a very important issue that @whuber touches on that you seem not to be dealing with at all -- indeed some of what you say implies that you don't realize it happens -- but I think it's directly relevant here. If you use a linear regression on a random variable that is ***homoscedastic*** (errors have constant variance), the residuals will actually be ***heteroscedastic*** (the residuals will not have constant variance). A number of answers on site show calculations for the variance of residuals.

Answer (score 0):

I may have found a sort of answer. 
In some cases (analysis of residuals, this terminology might be unprecise) standard deviation is calculated excluding a sample/data-point. 
The standard deviation so calculated, though calculated over all samples (minus one, "that" sample/data-point), is uniquely "identified" by the sample/data-point due to its exclusion from the computation.
(A similar thing seems to happen for standard error calculated for similar purposes)