# In simple linear regression, how does the derivation of the variance of the residues support its 'Constant Variance' Assumption?

Tags: regression, variance, residuals, error, linear

In simple linear regression: 
$$Residuals = \hat{Y} - Y$$

We can derive that:
$$Var(Residuals) = Var(\hat{Y} - Y) = (I-H)\cdot\sigma^2$$ ($\sigma^2$ is the variance of $Y$) 
(See [derivation of Var(residuals)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/115011/in-simple-linear-regression-where-does-the-formula-for-the-variance-of-the-resi))

So my question is:

> Since $h_{ii}$ (diagonal elements in H) is different for each $i$, how
>   come the $(I-H)\cdot\sigma^2$, which is the variance of the residuals,
>   is a constant (one of the assumptions of the LR)?

Another thing that bothers me is:

> We know that the MSE (which is calculated by the sum of squared
>   residuals divided by n-p) is an unbiased estimate of the variance of
>   the errors, so what are the relationships between MSE, the variance of
>   the errors and the variance of the residuals? Which one is the LR
>   assumption targeting at?

Comment: There's no assumption of constant variance of *residuals* in regression. There is a constant variance assumption however.  (BTW can you please be consistent with residuals vs "residues" in your Q? They should all be residuals)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comment! My confusion is that: one of the assumptions of LR is homoscedasticity -  (constant variance) of the ERRORS, and in order to check that, we usually generate residual plots, which are used to check whether the variance of the RESIDUALS is a constant; and given the derivation in the post, the variance of the RESIDUALS doesn't have to be a constant, so how can we use the residual plots to test the homoscedasticity property of the ERRORS? Thanks! And I will make the terms consistent in the post.

Comment: you're getting to the nub of an important question. Have you ever wondered why many stats packages by default offer plots not of raw residuals but residuals divided by $s\sqrt{1-h_{ii}}$? e.g. take a look at what R's `plot.lm`  does

Comment: @Glen_b, this is very insightful! It definitely helps a lot to clear my confusions, thank you sooo much!

Answer (score 2):

The assumption is that the errors have constant variance. The corresponding residuals don't have constant variance because points with larger values on the diagonal of the hat matrix ($H$) pull the fit more toward themselves than points with smaller values do, that is, they have greater influence on their own fitted value: $\dfrac{\partial \hat{y_i}}{\partial y_i}=h_{ii}$, the $i$th diagonal element of $H$.

As you say, the variance-covariance matrix of the residuals is given by $\sigma^2(I-H)$, which is normally estimated by $s^2(I-H)$, and so the standard error of the $i$th residual is $s\sqrt{1-h_{ii}}$.

As a result it's common to standardize residuals, scaling them to have constant variance: $\frac{y_i-\hat{y}_i}{s\sqrt{1-h_{ii}}}$.