# Is the variance of the residuals in linear regression constant (assuming constant-variance noise)?

Tags: regression, self-study, variance, residuals

In a linear regression model where $Y = X\beta+\epsilon$, with a residual vector $e=y-X\hat\beta$ where $\hat\beta=(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$ is the optimal regression coefficients given the data $X$ and $y$. Here $Var(e)=Var((I-X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T)y)=\sigma^2(I-H)$ if $H= X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$ and $Var(\epsilon) = \sigma^2I$, based on equation 10 on the second page [here](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/mreg/15/lectures/lecture-15.pdf). To me, $Var(e_i) = \sigma^2(I-H)_{ii}$ which is generally not constant for all $i$.

However, the same author [here](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/mreg/15/lectures/07/lecture-07.pdf) states that $Var(e_i)=\frac{n-2}{n}\sigma^2$ (page 3) and states that the residuals should show constant variance, unchanging with $x$ (page 5). On page 7 he further states that a plot of the residuals against the predictors should be look like a constant-width of points around a flat line of height zero since variance of the residual is constant and has expected value 0.

Is $Var(e_i)$ constant? Why do the two formulations above appear to say different things?

Comment: Answered here:   https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/291780/in-simple-linear-regression-how-does-the-derivation-of-the-variance-of-the-resi

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I saw that post as well, however if that's true then I don't get what my second source was getting at when it states explicitly that the variance of the residuals are constant with x

Comment: Note that he continues "though again I omit the details, so as not to spoil a future assignment". He just botched it. "Omitting the details" (usually from laziness) is where I am introducing all kinds of errors, at least. But just DO that exercise, and you will see he is wrong!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In simple linear regression, how does the derivation of the variance of the residues support its 'Constant Variance' Assumption?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/291780/in-simple-linear-regression-how-does-the-derivation-of-the-variance-of-the-resi)