# Demeaning variables in OLS

Tags: regression, variance, least-squares, linear-model, covariance

I am analysing some data in `R` where I have information on $y$ and $x$.
When I run $y = \alpha + \beta\cdot x$ I get the same coefficient on $x$ (i.e. $\beta$) as when I run
$$y = \beta  \cdot  (x - \bar{x})$$
But when I run
$$y - \bar{y} = \gamma \cdot x$$ I get a different coefficient on $x$.

I am really confused. Isn't the coefficient on $x$ meant to capture the covariance between $x$ and $y$, relative to the variance of $x$?

Why is it that demeaning the outcome variable ($y$) changes the coefficient on $x$ (when there is no intercept), but demeaning the independent variable ($x$) doesn't change it?

I tried to figure it out numerically but cannot recover this paradox.

Comment: If you included an intercept, the coefficient should be the same whether you center $y$ or not. Can you show the code you've used to fit the models?

Comment: @COOLSerdash, yes I know if I include the intercept it's the same. But I want to understand, why when I omit the intercept, the coefficient on x changes when I demean y.

Comment: Those are two different models and their coefficients don't even have the same meaning.

Comment: @whuber
But in Model 1 ) $y = \alpha + \beta .x $ 

in Model 2) $y =  \gamma . (x - \bar{x}) $ 
in Model 3) $y - \bar{y} =  \delta . x $ 

Don't i have $\beta = cov(x,y) / var(x)$ and $\gamma = cov(y, x - \bar{x})/var(x - \bar{x}) = cov(y,x)/var(x) = \beta$ and  $\delta = cov(y - \bar{y}, x)/var(x) = cov(y,x)/var(x) = \beta$
So should'nt $\alpha = \beta = \delta$ ?

Comment: In model 2 you are forcing $\alpha=\beta$ and in model 3 you are forcing $\alpha = \bar y.$  This is what algebra alone tells us.

Comment: Thanks @whuber, but then shouldn't all three coefficients $\beta$, $\gamma$ and $\alpha$ bet the same? following the comment above?

Comment: The Frisch Waugh Lovell theorem helps explain most of the points.

Comment: @ChristophHanck in what way?

Comment: Please see my answer

Answer (score 4):

#### The intercept-free model with centered $y$

> But when I run
> $$y - \bar{y} = \gamma . x$$ I get a different coefficient on x.

If you rewrite that equation,

$$y = \bar{y}  +  \gamma  x$$

then you see how it differs from your first case

$$y = \alpha + \beta x$$

[image: example]

---

#### The intercept-free model with centered $x$

The surprising part is not that $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are different, but that your second model, where you center the $x$ variable has the same slope with and without intercept.

$$y = \beta  (x - \bar{x})$$

The coefficient $\beta$ is for simple linear regression $y_i = \alpha + \beta x_i + \epsilon$

$$\beta = \frac{\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_i\right) - \bar{x}\bar{y}  }{\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2\right)-\bar{x}^2}$$

And for a model without intercept $y_i = \beta z_i + \epsilon$, with $z_i = x_i - \bar{x}$

$$\beta = \frac{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n z_iy_i}{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n z_i^2} = \frac{\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_i\right) - \bar{x}\bar{y}  }{\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2\right)-\bar{x}^2} $$

where the second equation occurs when we fill in $z_i = x_i - \bar{x}$

---

#### Intuition

One way to see the least squares method is as a orthogonal projection of the observation $\mathbf{y}$ onto the space spanned by the identity vector $\mathbf{1}$ (the intercept) and the vector $\mathbf{x}$ or a matrix $\mathbf{X}$ containing those two vectors.

When the vectors that form that span are orthogonal then the projection is independent from whether or not a particular term is included. The different coefficients can be computed independently.

See also the question [Intuition behind $(X^TX)^{-1}$ in closed form of w in Linear Regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/364554/intuition-behind-xtx-1-in-closed-form-of-w-in-linear-regression) . That term $(\mathbf{X^TX})^{-1}$ occurs in the computation of the projection and is a conversion of coefficients based on how much the different columns in $\mathbf{X}$ correlate with each other. It gives a conversion of coordinates $\boldsymbol{\alpha} = \mathbf{X^TY}$ to coordinates $\boldsymbol{\beta} = (\mathbf{X^T} \mathbf{X})^{-1}\mathbf{X^TY}$

[image: projection]

When the columns in $\mathbf{X}$ are orthogonal, then the $(\mathbf{X^T} \mathbf{X})^{-1}$ has all the offdiagonal terms zero

$$\beta_i = (\mathbf{X^T} \mathbf{X})^{-1}_{ii}  \mathbf{X^T_i} \mathbf{y} = \frac{\mathbf{X^T_i} \mathbf{y} }{\mathbf{X^T_i}\mathbf{X_i}}$$

Answer (score 3):

It is not necessarily true that $\operatorname{cov}(x, y) / \operatorname{var}(x)$ is the slope in the case that there is no intercept.

The solution to the least squares problem for [simple linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression) is easier to see if we write the formula for the slope equivalently as the following assuming an intercept term:

$$\hat{\beta} = \frac{\sum_i ((y_i - \bar{y})(x_i - \bar{x}))}{ \sum_i (x_i - \bar{x})^2}$$

but if there is no intercept the solution is

$$\hat{\beta} = \frac{\sum_i (y_ix_i) }{ \sum_i (x_i^2)}$$

Now the two are equal if $x_i - \bar{x}$ is used in place of $x_i$ in the latter as the denominators are then clearly the same and the numerators are equal because $\sum_i (-\bar{y}(x_i - \bar{x}))$ is zero but, in general, the two are not  equal.

The place this often appears is when deriving $R^2$ since one then needs to use corresponding formulas for intercept and no-intercept cases.

Notice that if we use $\alpha + \beta(x_i - \bar{x})$ that the intercept and slope columns of the model matrix, i.e. a column of 1's and a column equal to $x - \bar{x}$, are orthogonal so the projection onto the latter is independent of the intercept; however, if we remove $-\bar{x}$ then they are no longer necessarily orthogonal.

Answer (score 1):

I will discuss a general case of which your demeaning is a special case where $X_2$ is just the constant term, see [Utility of the Frisch-Waugh theorem](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/201919/utility-of-the-frisch-waugh-theorem/202030#202030).

The Frisch Waugh Lovell theorem tells us that the coefficient $\hat\beta_1$ on the variables $X_1$ of a regression of $y$ on $X_1$ and $X_2$ can

(a) be obtained as usual by regressing $y$ on both $X_1$ and $X_2$ or

(b) by first regressing *both*, in separate regressions, $y$ and $X_1$ on $X_2$, saving the residuals of these regressions. These can, using the ["residual maker matrix"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/117406/proof-that-the-coefficients-in-an-ols-model-follow-a-t-distribution-with-n-k-d/117422#117422) $M_{X_2}=I-X_2(X_2'X_2)^{-1}X_2'$, be written as $M_{X_2}y$ and $M_{X_2}X_1$. Then,  regress these residuals of the regression of $y$, $M_{X_2}y$, on those for the regressions for $X_1$, $M_{X_2}X_1$, or

(c) by only regressing $X_1$ on $X_2$, saving the residuals of these regressions and regress $y$ on the residuals for the regressions for $X_1$

Now, (b) can be written as, using the standard OLS formula,
$$
\hat{\beta}_{\text{ols},1}=(X_1'M_{X_2}'M_{X_2}X_1)^{-1}X_1'M_{X_2}'M_{X_2}y
$$
(to see this, just apply the general OLS expression $(X'X)^{-1}X'y$ to $X=M_{X_2}X_1$ and $y=M_{X_2}y$).

I skip that this is the same as (a), cf. e.g. [Frisch-Waugh-Lovell theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frisch%E2%80%93Waugh%E2%80%93Lovell_theorem).

Why is the same as (c)?

Notice that $M_{X_2}$ is symmetric and [idempotent](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/115011/in-simple-linear-regression-where-does-the-formula-for-the-variance-of-the-resi/115048#115048) (i.e., $M_{X_2}'M_{X_2}=M_{X_2}M_{X_2}=M_{X_2}$), so that we may as well write
$$
\hat{\beta}_{\text{ols},1}=(X_1'M_{X_2}'M_{X_2}X_1)^{-1}X_1'M_{X_2}'y
$$
(or $(X_1'M_{X_2}X_1)^{-1}X_1'M_{X_2}y$, if we wish), which is (c). This is what your regression of $y$ on demeaned $x$ amounts to.

It is (unless $M_{X_2}X_1=X_1\Leftrightarrow X_1'X_2=0$, i.e. unless regressors are orthogonal - in your case, unless $x$ has sample mean zero) however *not* the same as writing
$$
(X_1'X_1)^{-1}X_1'M_{X_2}y.
$$
This is what your regression of demeaned $y$ on $x$ amounts to.